# Substrings from iterable node

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

Please consider this sample file: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/books.xml

This XPath expression `//title/text()`, returns:

> Everyday Italian
>   Harry Potter
>   XQuery Kick Start
>   Learning XML

Now I want just the first names, and try: `tokenize(//title/text(),' ')[1]`, which returns:

> Too many items

OTOH `tokenize((//title/text())[1],' ')[1]` returns first name for first node.

How can I get substrings with XPath while iterating nodes?

Comment: theta, Was my answer useful to you or do you still have any problems? Did you notice that it is at least twice shorter than the currently accepted answer, and more efficient?

Comment: Regards Dimitre. Thanks for you additional answer (which I up-voted), and for included tips and further explanation. It is very useful and I hope, others will soon up-vote, too. I already marked Cylian's answer as correct, as it showed me the mistake and lead me to `//title/tokenize(text(),' ')[1]` solution, which was perfect for my problem. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

**1. To get all parts except last one use this:**

```
//title/string-join(tokenize(.,'\s+')[position() ne last()],' ')
```

or

**2. To get only first one use this:**

```
//title/string-join(tokenize(.,'\s+')[position() eq 1],' ')
```

**Hope this helps.**

Comment: Ah, thanks, that give me the clue. So function should not be called on whole XPath expression but just on part returning text. This is however much simpler then: `//title/tokenize(text(),' ')[1]` and it works great. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
//text()/tokenize(.,' ')[1]
```

This produces a sequence of the first "word" of every text node in the XML document.

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:sequence select="//text()/tokenize(.,' ')[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
    <a>Everyday Italian</a>
    <b>Harry Potter</b>
    <c>XQuery Kick Start</c>
    <d>Learning XML</d>
</t>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
 Everyday 
 Harry 
 XQuery 
 Learning
```

The above includes a few white-space only text nodes.

**If you want to ignore any whitespace-only text node, change the XPath expression to**:

```
//text()[normalize-space()]/tokenize(.,' ')[1]
```